# What can I use to clean my brick fireplace

Tags: brick, fireplace, grout

I have a brick fireplace that has been great over the years. I was wondering, since I can't pressure-wash the grout or brick with a cleaner, what can I use to bring the brick and grout back to life?

Comment: For outdoors, use diluted pool acid (muriatic acid) and a scrub brush. Wear goggles, rubber gloves, coveralls. Rinse with clear water afterwards.

Answer (score -1):

What we did with our 32 year old brick fireplace was paint it white. It was a lot easier than trying to clean the brick and grout.

Comment: Thanks for the idea but this doesn't really answer my question and I'm not interested in painting it.

Comment: Aww, what a shame to cover up masonry with paint!